# Azure API Management Policy(Rewrite URI policy)- Template and Query Parameters

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management, azure-policy

I require some help on doing a rewrite uri policy. I was able to extract information from payload and change the initial request URL. Have extracted the insurer_id from body and passed it to my backend -> mybackend.com/api/relationship/deny/{insurer_id}

I was able to extract it and send it to my backend, I have a bit of a trouble formatting once the request has been posted

I have a current payload:

```json
{
  "insurer_id": "22112",
  "insurer_name": "Steve Rogers",
  "status_code: [ " "Deny\",",
  ],
  "additionalComments": "This is a test"
}
```

This is my Current code:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="insurerId" value="@{
            var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
            return body["insurer_id"].Value<string>();
        }" />
        <set-variable name="status_code" value="@{
                return context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent:true)["status_code"].ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
            }" />
        <rewrite-uri template="@("/api/relationship/deny/" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("insurerId") + "?denyReason=" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("status_code"))" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://testbackend.azure-api.net" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

What I am trying to achieve works, but when I do a post, the payload doesn't look what is to be expected.

Expected Payload:

```json
{
  "insurer_id": "22112",
  "insurer_name": "Steve Rogers",
  "status_code": "Deny",
  "additionalComments": "This is a test"
}
```

Unformatted payload:

```json
{
  "insurer_id": "22112",
  "insurer_name": "Steve Rogers",
  "status_code": "[\"Deny\"]",
  "additionalComments": "This is a test"
}
```

Comment: Just just asked this very same question not that long ago..... [Azure API Management Policy(Rewrite URI)- Template Paramets and Query Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615589/azure-api-management-policyrewrite-uri-template-paramets-and-query-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the first value of your JArray and assign it to the variable:

```
<set-variable name="status_code" value="@{
        var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
        var statusCode = body["status_code"] as JArray;
        if(statusCode != null && statusCode.Count > 0)
        {
            return statusCode.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return null;
}" />
```

But therefore you have to fix your invalid JSON:

```json
{
  "insurer_id": "22112",
  "insurer_name": "Steve Rogers",
  "status_code": [ "Deny"],
  "additionalComments": "This is a test"
}
```

A [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) consists of a key-value pair:

> https://example.com/over/there?name=ferret

`name` is the key
`ferret` is the value for it

In your example, there's no key:

`? + denyReason=context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("status_code")`
and also the `?` is a string. So it has to be put between quotation marks.

Fixed with sample query-key `status_code`:

```xml
<rewrite-uri template="@("/api/relationship/deny/" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("insurerId") + "?statuscode=" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("status_code"))" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
```

Complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="insurerId" value="@{
            var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
            return body["insurer_id"].Value<string>();
        }" />
        <set-variable name="status_code" value="@{
                var body = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
                var statusCode = body["status_code"] as JArray;
                if(statusCode != null && statusCode.Count > 0)
                {
                    return statusCode.FirstOrDefault();
                }
                return null;
         }" />
        <rewrite-uri template="@("/api/relationship/deny/" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("insurerId") + "?statuscode=" + context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("status_code"))" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://testbackend.azure-api.net" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```